# Cannot use License in Visual Studio on specific machine

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a MSDN-(gold) account to use VS. On my local machine I can login without problems.

On a machine I connect through RDP I cannot use my credentials. The Firewalls have been configured to allow connection to the microsoft servers and VS even connects successful. The login has no error, even my picture is displayed. So I do not expect a firewall issue.

Nonetheless VS says: "The downloaded license is insufficent" (Translated by me. Wording might be a bit different. Original was: "Die heruntergeladene Lizenz ist unzureichend")

This is VS 2013 Professional and my License should be more than sufficiant for that. (Works fine with my local VS 2013 premium)

Surprisingly there isn't a SINGLE result on Google to that issue. So you are my last hope :)

Comment: how to you connect to your work-machine - `mstsc`? What if you use the remote-machine directly? In the end it will be the firewall on premise (I know the pain)

Comment: We sniffed the traffic. No package (at least http/https) has been blocked. So this should not be a firewall issue. No chance to use the machine directly.

Comment: well sorry no clue then

Comment: @leppie Done that a dozen times. Did not help